# Isometry of surfaces implies equal coefficients of the first fundamental form

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

In my differential geometry course isometric surfaces were defined as having parametrizations $\textbf{r}_{1} = \textbf{f}(u,v)$ and 
$\textbf{r}_{2} = \textbf{f}(u,v)$ such that $\textbf{r}_{1}$, $\textbf{r}_{2}$ : $D \rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}^3$, where $D$ is open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and for each plane curve $l$ on $D$ lengths of their images are equal: $|\textbf{r}_1(l)| = |\textbf{r}_2(l)|$.

To proof that the first fundamental form completely describes the metric properties of a surface we need to proof:

1. That surfaces with equal coefficients of the first fundamental form are isometric
2. That any isometric surfaces have parametrizations with equal coefficients of the first fundamental form.

Length of the curves on the surface are calcutated with coefficients of the first fundamental form, so it's quite easy to proof that equality of them implies surfaces' isometry.

But how can the second statement be proved?

Comment: Of course, you mean to have $\mathbf g(u,v)$ for $\mathbf r_2$. You want to show that if the equality on lengths holds (for the given parametrizations) for all $\ell$, then the first fundamental forms match up. If there were some point $(u_0,v_0)$ at which they are *not* equal, you should be able to choose a very short path $\ell$ starting at that point where the length integrals will not be equal. (For example, what if the first entry of the first fundamental forms are different? Etc.)